# Estuturar banco de dados, tabela de endereço para duas entidades diferentes

Tags: banco-de-dados, tabela-banco-de-dados

Tenho essas quatro tabelas:

```
Clientes | Lojas | Endereço | Contato
```

Como tanto `lojas` quanto `clientes` possuem **endereço** e **telefones para contato**, existe apenas uma unica tabela para `endereços` e `contatos`, para identificar cada registro existe um prefixo para cada inserção: **C** para cliente e **L** para loja, então tenho registros assim: `tabela contatos`

```
ContatoId | contato_dddCelular | contato_celular | contato_dddtellefone | contato_telefone
C1        |11                  | 912341234       |11                    |12341234
L1        |21                  | 912341234       |21                    |12341234
```

existem algumas `views` no `mysql` que estão apresentando uma lentidão absurda, após fazer alguns testes percebi que o problema era justamente alguns `joins` que estão sendo feitos com a função `Concat()`, algo como `join contatos on Concat("C",clientes.clienteId) = contatos.ContatoId)`, após remover esses `join` as consultas foram feitas quase que instantâneamente, minha duvida é a seguinte qual seria um **relacionamento alternativo** ou ideal para corrigir esse problema sem ter que criar duas tabelas de endereços e contatos?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olha amigo, estou vendo um erro que eu considero ser o preponderante do motivo de seu código estar dando problemas.

Sua modelagem está incorreta.

O que me levou a essa conclusão: vc está trabalhando com campos de texto - misturando letra e número - numa coluna ID.

Bancos de dados lidam melhor com números, evite usar qualquer coisa diferente disso para o campo ID.

Se como consequência vc ainda estiver precisando usar a coluna *ContatoId* do mesmo jeito, isso implica que você está modelando de forma incorreta o banco.

Vamos lá. Blza, temos Clientes, temos Lojas. Lojas tem endereço, clientes tem endereço, blza, endereço permanece o mesmo para os dois, uma tabela Endereços, e nos clientes e nas lojas temos uma coluna de referência (*foreign key*) para ela.

O que vc não entendeu é o seguinte: uma loja tem N clientes, um cliente pode ser "cliente" de mais de uma loja - M lojas); então, na relação loja para cliente, temos uma relação N para M (ou M para N).

Qual a implicação disso? Simples, quando temos uma relação N para M, temos algo que chamamos de entidade associativa, que nada mais é do que outra tabela. Ela tem um ID de referência tanto para o cliente quanto para a loja.

Pelo que entendi, nessa modelagem, essa entidade associativa é o contato. (loja contato cliente).

Isso implica em duas coisas:

1. Se o cliente puder dar 2 endereços diferentes para duas lojas, eu aconselho a tirar a coluna endereço do cliente, assim, uma loja só vai ter conhecimento do endereço dele quando ele se tornar contato dela.
2. Se isso não importar para a sua modelagem, ou seja, uma vez que o cliente atualize o endereço em qualquer loja, ela valha para todas, vc deixa a referência a endereço na tabela cliente.

A mesma coisa vale para telefone. Só que a loja tem um telefone - isso fica na própria tabela loja - e o número de telefone pode ficar tanto na tabela contato quanto na tabela cliente, da mesma forma que acabei de explicar.

O telefone não precisa de ter uma tabela a mais, mesmo que vc coloque aí também celular. É trabalho demais para pouco retorno.

O endereço você pode até não criar uma tabela a mais, isso vai te poupar muitos joins, hoje em dia nem tem muita importância vc ter um modelo 100% normalizado, talvez se vc faça análises significativas com endereço faça alguma diferença, mas mais uma vez é muito trabalho para pouco retorno.

Comment: acho que entendi: no modelo que esta aqui o **id do cliente** vai para a tabela **endereço**, da forma que explicou, eu traria o **id do endereço** para a tabela cliente? ( e sim, o cliente atualiza o endereço em qualquer loja, e é um endereço só )

Comment: Quase isso, o cliente precisa de um ID para endereço. Mas o endereço não precisa do ID do cliente, vc pode ter um marido e uma mulher clientes de uma loja e ambos vivem no mesmo endereço.

Answer (score 0):

Eu particularmente não entendi a necessidade e identificar por uma código qual endereço pertence a quem se o id do endereço deve estar necessariamente atrelado ao cliente ou loja a que pertence. Por exemplo, o endereço de id 7 sempre vai ser referenciado à loja L1 ou ao cliente C40 (números arbitrário para mostrar a ideia). Pelo menos essa é a interpretação que faço. A meu ver basta referenciar corretamente o id do endereço e o id da entidade detentora (cliente ou loja) na tabela de junção.
No entanto, pode-se refletir melhor sobre isso se tu postar as suas tabelas para que se possa analisá-las com maior cuidado.

Comment: o prefixo é justamente pra diferenciar, o campo `ContatoId` faz referencia tanto para a tabela `cliente` quanto para tabela `loja`, imagina o cenario que tenho registro na tabela lojas: `idLoja | 1` e na tabela contato insiro esse mesmo id `contatoid | 1`, quando fosse cadastrar um cliente, `clienteId | 1` ao inserir na tabela contato já teria outro registro com `id 1`, não sei se ficou claro